# Taylor expansion of exponential around 0 for $x = O(1)$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Let $x$ be some real value that is $O(1)$, find the taylor expansion of $e^tx$ at $0$.

The text I am following writes:

$$e^tx = 1 + tx + O(t^2x^2e^{O(t)})$$

I'm confused why there is an additional factor of $e^{O(t)}$.

See the proof of lemma 1: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/01/03/254a-notes-1-concentration-of-measure/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see, by Taylor, there is a number $c$ between $0$ and $tx$ (thus $c=O(t)$ )such that:
$$ e^{tx}=1+tx+\dfrac{1}{2} (tx)^2 e^{c}$$

Hence, the conclusion.

Comment: I see, it's an application of mean value theorem. Thanks!